# How to track MP3 downloads so to report on total plays

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I’m writing a simple app to play MP3 files both from a stream and on-demand.  I want to get some basic stats on how many times each on-demand MP3 was played.  My streaming hosting provider does not provide stats for on-demand MP3s so I want to build it myself.  I was thinking, when the user presses the play button the first time I hit a file on my site and then track that file using  my existing analytics software.   Or…???

This is my question.  What do you guys recommend the best way to store this info (simple count of total plays per mp3).

Thank you very much

p.s. I've ben wrestling with this one for a bit and to be honest, i don't even know how to ask the question or what title to use.  LOL.  :(  Sorry, I hope my description makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest saving simply an integer on the NSUserDefaults when offline and tick the file on your server to track the plays with a simple POST request. Then when the application is back online post the value of NSUserDefaults and make the sum after reinitializing it.

I am not sure if I understood what you want to do, that is what I would do.